# reference another column with tidyeval in filter

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I have a `tibble` with column `foo` that contains the name of another column in the tibble. I'd like to filter based on the column that is named in `foo`:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(foo = c(rep("carb", 16), rep("gear", 16))) %>%
  filter(!!sym(foo) == 4)
#> Error in is_symbol(x): object 'foo' not found
```

It seems to be looking for `foo` in the global environment, so I think I need a way to specify that `foo` should be evaluated in the context of the tibble.

Desired result would be the same as running:

```
rbind(
  mtcars[1:16,] %>% mutate(foo = "carb") %>% filter(carb == 4),
  mtcars[17:32,] %>% mutate(foo = "gear") %>% filter(gear == 4)
)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  foo
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 carb
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 carb
#> 3  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 carb
#> 4  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 carb
#> 5  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 carb
#> 6  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 carb
#> 7  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 carb
#> 8  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 gear
#> 9  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 gear
#> 10 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 gear
#> 11 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 gear
#> 12 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 gear
```

Comment: Will it vary every row, or would be in chunks?

Comment: It could vary every row.

Answer (score 3):

If 'foo' is already a column with "am" as string, select the first element of 'foo', convert it to `sym`bol, evaluate (`!!`) and `filter` those rows where the value of 'am' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
mtcars %>%
   mutate(foo = "am") %>%
   filter(!! sym(foo[1]) == 1)
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb foo
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  am
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  am
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  am
#4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1  am
#5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2  am
#6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1  am
#7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1  am
#8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2  am
#9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2  am
#10 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4  am
#11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6  am
#12 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8  am
#13 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2  am
```

---

If this varies every row, then an efficient option would be row/column indexing

```
df1 <- mtcars %>%
           mutate(foo = c(rep("carb", 16), rep("gear", 16)))
i1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), match(df1$foo, names(df1)))
subset(df1, df1[-ncol(df1)][i1] == 4)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  foo
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 carb
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 carb
#7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 carb
#10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 carb
#11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 carb
#15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 carb
#16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 carb
#18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 gear
#19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 gear
#20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 gear
#26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 gear
#32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 gear
```

or an option is `get` with `rowwise`

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    filter(get(foo) == 4)
```

---

Or use the row/column indexing in `filter`

```
df1 %>% 
      filter(.[cbind(row_number(), match(foo, names(.)))] == 4)
```

Comment: Closer to the second one, except `foo` needs to be a column, rather than a separate object. I'll make a harder example so this is clearer

Comment: `foo` can vary, so `[1]` won't work. See improved example and test.

Comment: I like the `get` solution, but `rowwise` has a big efficiency penalty. I know `eval_tidy` can be used to evaluate expressions in a given context, so I think it could work here but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: @lost it also works with `rowwise` `df1 %>% rowwise %>% filter(eval_tidy(sym(foo)) == 4)`

Comment: yeah, this works, but takes a while to run on my actual tibble. Is there an `eval_tidy` solution that doesn't require `rowwise`?

Comment: @lost I doubt so, because it requires a row index as well, otherwise, it is not going to understand which row the value should be selected

Comment: @lost if you need a quicker option, try `df1 %>% filter(.[cbind(row_number(), match(foo, names(.)))] == 4)`

Comment: Yes, the point @akrun made about row ambiguity explains why the syntax `filter(!!sym(foo) == 4)` just wouldn't work. For each of the 32 rows in mtcars, you'd be telling dplyr to evaluate whether the 32 entries in carb or gear equal 4.

Comment: @bschneidr so are `tidyeval` functions not vectorized like other functions, then? c.f., if I do `mtcars %>% mutate(am1 = am + 1)` I don't have to tell `dplyr` to do this one row at a time.

Comment: The problem isn't that the `tidyeval` function `sym` isn't vectorized. The problem is that, even if `sym` were vectorized, the code `!!sym(foo)` for each value of `foo` would return the entire length-32 vector found by "looking-up" the object in the data frame whose name is given by `foo`. So the result of vectorizing would be a list of 32 vectors, each of length 32.

Comment: I have added an answer that is vectorised. @akrun your first example doesn't work for me. Do you have an object `foo` in your workspace?

Comment: I think we can state the vectorisation issue as follows: an expression may represent a vectorised operation, but here you have constructed a problem where you need to create as many expressions as there are rows, because the expression depends on row values.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid tidy eval here and work with values. First create the vector `foo` containing the relevant values from `carb` and `gear`, then filter it:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(foo = c(carb[1:16], gear[1:16])) %>%
  filter(foo == 4)
```

If the provenance of the values is variable:

```r
df <- mtcars[1:5, ]
cols <- c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")

assemble_from <- function(data, cols) {
  map2_dbl(seq_along(cols), cols, function(i, c) data[[i, c]])
}

df %>%
  mutate(foo = assemble_from(df, cols)) %>%
  filter(foo %in% 1:3)

# Or more simply
df %>%
  filter(assemble_from(df, cols) %in% 1:3)
```

Comment: Good point, I have added an example of how to reconstruct a vector rowwise.

Comment: coming back to this now, is there still not a way to tideval a column's name? It's inconvenient having to create a bespoke function for this, and forces me to interrupt a pipe or use `{}` for what should be a pretty simple operation.

Comment: I read again the post but I'm a bit confused by the question. With `filter()` we generally compare two columns together using a vectorised predicate that compares all values row by row. Here you have a column of column names. So each row should be compared against a different column? This seems like a pretty complex operation to me.

Comment: I've added a new answer that hopefully better answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `filter()` expressions compare two columns with a vectorised predicate that looks at each values row by row. In this case we have a column of column names that determines which column to look at for each row. We can solve this problem using `get()` and `rowwise()`.

- Tidyeval tools are made for columns that are defined externally (e.g. in a function argument). Here the columns are defined inside the data frame. That's unusual because column names defined in a data frame necessarily vary row by row. In any case, since the columns are defined in the data frame, `get()` seems the best tool to use here.
- Since we have a row-by-row problem, we need to transform the data frame to a rowwise df. This way expressions inside `mutate()` etc will be evaluated once by row. Note that `rowwise()` patterns have a performance cost because they are not vectorised, so they should be limited to a small part of the code.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(foo = c(rep("carb", 16), rep("gear", 16))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(get(foo) == 4)
```